# An irreducible analytic sub-variety of a complex manifold is connected.

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I am trying to see if the statement is correct. I think it should be.

**An irreducible analytic sub-variety $V$ of a complex manifold $M$ is connected.** The locus of smooth points of $V$ is denoted as $V^*$ and the locus of the singular points are denoted as $V_{\text{s}}$. Now I want to use the result: *An analytic variety $V$ is irreducible iff $V^*$ is connected.* Now clearly $V^*$ is open. I want to say that $V^*$ is also dense. Does it follow from Sard's theorem? because locally $V$ looks like zeroes of a finite collection of holomorphic functions. And then I want to say that $V^*$ is connected $\Rightarrow \overline{V^*}=V$ is connected. Can anyone help?

Comment: An irreducible topological space is trivially connected: check the definitions. Singular or smooth points are completely irrelevant.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Silly me; totally missed it. Thanks.